# Trouble with || operator

Tags: php, logical-operators

I have a page (titled PPC) and a custom post type (titled Presentations) that I don't want certain elements to appear on.  I thought this code would work :

```
 <?php
      if ((!is_page('PPC')) || (!is_singular('presentations'))) {
      ?>
        <section id="menu" class="menu">
          <div class="grid grid--justify-center grid-md--justify-end grid--align-middle menu__inner">
            <nav role="navigation" class="menu__nav">
              <?php
              $nav_classes = 'header__menu header__menu--global';
              include(locate_template('components/component-nav.php', false, false));
              ?>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </section>

        <div class="header__item header__item--hamburger">
          <button id="toggleHeaderHamburger" onclick="toggleHeaderView()" class="hamburger">
            <span class="hamburger__bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>

      <?php } ?>
```

Using each conditional by itself, without the ||, works fine.  But when I combine them both and use the logical operator, nothing works.  I've also tried taking the wrapping parentheses out as well, so it looks like this:

```
if (!is_page('PPC')) || (!is_singular('presentations')) {
```

But then I get an error.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please say, in plain english, what you want that `if()` statement to do.

Comment: I want it to exclude (not show) the section element and it's sibling div element from displaying on the PPC page, and also on the Presentations custom post type.

Comment: <?php if ((!is_page('PPC')) || (!is_singular('presentations'))) : ?>
html code
<?php endif; ?>
this method is more clear, and you dont need to deal with paranthesis,

Comment: @amamoslavida tried that too - no luck

Comment: Can you write the error ?

Comment: I don't get an error with your code, just doesn't do anything for some reason.  But the error I've been getting with that last little bit was 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '||'

Comment: BTW that error is from mistmatched parentheses in your edited version. You seem to have just stripped off the outer quotes instead of the two inner sets of quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've written it, `!is_page('PPC') || !is_singular('presentations')` would roughly translate it as "one of neither of these" which is a logical absurbity. Within the evaulation of that expression, if it's "not a PPC" it no longer matters whether or not it is "a presentation", and vice-versa.

What you want is "either of these" `is_page('PPC') || is_singular('presentations')` prefixed with a "not" for:

`! ( is_page('PPC') || is_singular('presentations') )`

"Not either of these".